# Why is my merge sort algorithm not working?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am implementing the merge sort algorithm in Python. Previously, I have implemented the same algorithm in C, it works fine there, but when I implement in Python, it outputs an unsorted array.

I've already rechecked the algorithm and code, but to my knowledge the code seems to be correct.

I think the issue is related to the scope of variables in Python, but I don't have any clue for how to solve it.

```
from random import shuffle
# Function to merge the arrays
def merge(a,beg,mid,end):
    i = beg
    j = mid+1
    temp = []
    while(i<=mid and j<=end):
        if(a[i]<a[j]):
            temp.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            temp.append(a[j])
            j += 1
    if(i>mid):
        while(j<=end):
            temp.append(a[j])
            j += 1
    elif(j>end):
        while(i<=mid):
            temp.append(a[i])
            i += 1

    return temp



# Function to divide the arrays recursively
def merge_sort(a,beg,end):
    if(beg<end):
        mid = int((beg+end)/2)
        merge_sort(a,beg,mid)
        merge_sort(a,mid+1,end)
        a = merge(a,beg,mid,end)

    return a

a = [i for i in range(10)]
shuffle(a)
n = len(a)
a = merge_sort(a, 0, n-1)
print(a)
```

Comment: In `merge`, you don't seem to be doing anything with `temp` after you populate it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edited my code and description. Could you please recheck it?

Comment: Just add some debug output and see where it goes wrong. Also its "return temp"

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Compare debug-output with what you would expect when performing the merge-sort manually.

Comment: @MrSmith42 yes, I tried everything. I feel that its the issue of the array not getting copied properly into the original one, but I just don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Technically a inevery case is a complete array. Temp on the other hand is no longer than beg-end, so even if it did get copied it'd mess everything up. I'll add an explanation in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you need to change `merge_sort` declaration slightly:

```
def merge_sort(a,beg,end):
    if(beg<end):
        mid = int((beg+end)/2)
        merge_sort(a,beg,mid)
        merge_sort(a,mid+1,end)
        a[beg:end+1] = merge(a,beg,mid,end)  # < this line changed
    return a
```

## Why:

`temp` is constructed to be no longer than end-beg+1, but a is the initial full array, if you managed to replace all of it, it'd get borked quick. Therefore we take a "slice" of `a` and replace values in that slice.

## Why not:

Your `a` luckily was not getting replaced, because of Python's inner workings, that is a bit tricky to explain but I'll try.
Every variable in Python is a reference. `a` is a reference to a list of variables `a[i]`, which are in turn references to a constantant in memory.
When you pass `a` to a function it makes a new local variable `a` that points to the same list of variables. That means when you reassign it as `a=***` it only changes where `a` points. You can only pass changes outside either via "slices" or via `return` statement

## Why "slices" work:

Slices are tricky. As I said `a` points to an array of other variables (basically `a[i]`), that in turn are references to a constant data in memory, and when you reassign a slice it goes trough the slice element by element and changes where those individual variables are pointing, but as `a` inside and outside are still pointing to same old elements the changes go through.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Wow. Amazing explanation! I never knew this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the results of the recursive merges, so you essentially report the result of the merge of the two unsorted halves.